# C Data structure how to declare

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

I am stuck on the on how to manipulate the data structure.

I have header file that declare like this

```
struct item{
 int    i;  
 char   str[88];
};
```

and  I have a **C** file that I want to make 9 structure items (I declare as global variable and I already include the header file):

```
struct item a[9];
```

but when I want to put the data that I want into

```
foo()

    {
    ...
      // let's say I have data int in index and char[] in string
      // and I want it to put at item_index

      a[item_index].i = index;
      a[item_index].str = string;
    ...
    }
```

but when ever I tried to compile it seem that it always shows

```
error: expected an identifiler
```

Comment: You need to use [strcpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) to assign to `str` - `strcpy(a[item_index].str, string)`

Comment: You're basically doing everything right.  The only problem is that you can't just assign a C string with "="; you need to use a function like "strcpy()".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a[item_index].str = string;
```

This line will not behave the way you expect it to. You would need to use `strcpy()` in order to copy strings:

```
strcpy(a[item_index].str, string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Array Name is a non modifiable (read only) variable or better say constant.

In this statement:

`a[item_index].str = string;`

you try to modify an array `str`, it is not permissible.

Either you can assign value to each index one by one (that is what done by `strcpy`),
Or declare a pointer `*str` instead of array and then assign it any address you want.